# Start emacs as tcp server

Tags: server

I'm using GNU Emacs 26.0.50.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.5) of 2016-12-20, with arch linux (antergos), I want to start with the option tcp  server, so I added and assigment to the variable server-use-tcp,

(setq server-use-tcp t)

and I get this warning:

```
In toplevel form:
init.el:15:7:Warning: assignment to free variable ‘server-use-tcp’
```

Is this variable deleted?, or is the wrong way to this? or what library I need to require before setting that variable?

Comment: This variable is defined in `server.el`. Could you try to `(require 'server)` before you set this variable?

Comment: Indeed.  Running `server-start` also makes it available (through autoloading).  Note this is not new to emacs 26.